# Opera 12 lost all my bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks, opera

I updated to Opera 12 (Windows XP) some days ago, and since then Opera is crashing and running unstable. 
So today while browsing, an error message came up - something like *"couldn't save bookmarks.adr"*. 
I restarted Opera and all my bookmarks are gone!

How to recover them?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to import the file from an old backup.

If you don't have an backup you may try to extract the old bookmarks.adr file from the `System Volume Information` directory. If you have not disabled System Restore the bookmarks.adr is most likely saved in there. 
However extracting the file is pretty complex as you first have to get access to the directory (unhide, take ownership, set access permissions) and then you have to find the file based on it's content as the filename is different.

On Windows 7 it would be easy as it includes the volume shadow copy service which can be accessed via context menu of the file.

Comment: Isn't there a .tmp file Opera creates of bookmarks and notes?

Comment: I am not sure if a tmp file is used. If you try a undelete software look for file that contains only text and starts with `Opera Hotlist version 2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

When this also happened to me previously (my bookmarks were also 'reset'), what I did was went to `%AppData%\Opera\Opera` (Opera's 'application data' directory - it is this directory in my installation of Opera: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Opera\Opera`). Then, I right-clicked *Bookmarks.adr* > Previous Version > click on *Restore...* button > and then restored a previous version. I got my old bookmarks back.

Now, I use [Opera Launcher](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/opera-launcher) to automatically create daily backups of my bookmarks (*Bookmarks.adr* file). [Instructions for installation and configuration of Opera Launcher on a 64-bit OS here](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/show.dml/2752759?startidx=200#comment63184142). It can also create backups of bookmarks and sessions.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to import anything! go to sync.opera.com sign in and all of your bookmarks will be there! I just found a page i have been looking for, for the past hour. I saved it years ago and when I went to look at it again it was gone, decided on a whim to log into my actual opera account and boom there they were!